# How to stop V10 asking to continue with updated styling each time I open a new notebook

Tags: notebooks, version-10

Each time I open a new notebook, using File->New->Notebook, I get this message

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then I check on the "Do this for all notebooks". But when I repeat this and want to create a new notebook, it asks again. Restarted M and still no change.  Any idea what can cause this and how to resolve it?

[image]

I am on window 7, 64 bit. Version 10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an option in Preferences > Interface that I think will fix this for you.
[image]